# Perform tests on multiple links opened from a list of links in Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, e2e-testing

I have read the links present on one web page and kept in a list. For those links I want to run simultaneous tests. I have 90 links on a page and for each pages I will run the same tests. I am trying to use multi-threading.
Is it possible to run the tests driven by the links in my list?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: @user8674283 Possible but you shouldn't